# Eclipse : what next when Reset Perspective does nothing?

Tags: eclipse, perspective, multiscreen

I tryed to move a perspective (DDMS) to my second monitor.
When i've drag/dropped the last window of my perspective to my second screen, then the perspective totally disapeared !

no more windows from the perspective anywhere
the tab of the perspective also disapeared.

I click

```
Window > Show Perspective > Others > DDMS
```

to force its "focus" then

```
Window>Reset Perspective
```

But nothing happens, i've lost DDMS perspective.

What can i do now to restore it?

Bonus Question : can we place a perspective in a second screen?

Comment: I finnally found the solution. Here what to do: 1)Make sure the perspective is opened (Window > Show Perspective > YourPerspective) 2)Reset It (Window > Reset Perspective) 3) Close ALL perspective (it doesn't works if you only close the problematic one.4)Reopen the perspective (see step 1).

Comment: You can open a New Window and have it in the second screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnally found the solution, here what to do:
1)Make sure the perspective is opened

```
Window > Show Perspective > YourPerspective
```

2)Reset It

```
Window > Reset Perspective
```

3) Close ALL perspective **it doesn't works if you only close the problematic one.**

```
Window > Close All Perspectives
```

4)Reopen the perspective (see step 1).
Job Done.